# Dynamic inner join using case statement (or similar)

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to inner join **table1** <- to -> **table2, table3, table4 OR table5** depending on a field present in **table1**. So, if the field ***information*** in *table1* has the value **example_get_from_two** I should inner join **table1 with table2** as to obtain a given row, if in another row *table1* has the value **example_get_from_three** I should inner join **table1 with table3** and so on. This is the query I tried, but it returned zero rows:

```
SELECT n.notification_type, 
  (CASE WHEN n.notification_type = 'two' AND n.information = t2.somefield
            THEN t2.anotherfield
        WHEN n.notification_type = 'three' 
            THEN (CASE WHEN t3.field = '1' THEN t3.otherfield ELSE t3.yetanotherfield END)
        WHEN n.notification_type = 'four' AND t4.field = n.information 
            THEN t4.anotherfield
        WHEN n.notification_type = 'five' 
            THEN t5.field
   END) AS information FROM table0 zero, notifications n
        INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON(n.information=t1.somefield AND n.notification_type = 'something')
        INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON(n.information=t2.somefield AND n.notification_type = 'something')
        INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON((n.information=t3.somefield OR n.information=t3.someotherfield) AND n.notification_type = 'something') 
WHERE zero.field ='something' AND n.id = zero.id
```

Unfortunately this retrieves zero rows and shouldn't , probably because all joins are made despite the actual value of information, and ***n.notification_type*** = "something". Is this possible with cases or similar? What I'd like to obtain is

> fromfield1   | fromfield2 | fromfield3 (this one is "dynamic" and
>   depends on the joined table)

Comment: Use a `left join` instead

Comment: @juergend https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1PvBc2TOpE4 ty so much